# Delphi VCL "TaskDialog" problem in Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, vcl, delphi-2007

I'm developing an windows app on Delphi 2007 and I'm using "Ttaskdialog" component in it. Using windows XP it runs normally, but in Windows 7 I'm getting the following message:

*TtaskDialog requires themes to be enabled*

Any clues how to fix it?

Comment: I thought an app that uses TTaskDialog wouldn't run on XP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use TTaskDialog you need to enable themes in project options.

In menu go to **Project** -> **Options...**
then to **Application**
and check the **Enable runtime themes** box.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it fully helped my problem.